# Automating Sharepoint Foundation 2013 Installation and Deployment of Project

Tags: deployment, solution-package, setup

I'm a long time software developer with absolutely no experience in Sharepoint.

I have just joined a new company and I was asked by the team leader to create an installer for Sharepoint Foundation 2013 and a working Sharepoint solution made by the company, preferably using HTA.

I have experimented installing it manually and deploying the solution, however, what's the best method to automate these two steps?

I was thinking of something like AutoSPInstaller, and after the end of the installation, I would run Add-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution commands for deploying the solution.

What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

AutoSpInstaller is good tool for automating the installation and configuration of SharePoint farm. But you have to customized it according to your need. because the by default Auto sp installer configure all the services application(even you dont need it) and couple of web apps. I would do the 3 steps method.

- I would customized it to create the required services application and
  then create one web application.
- After that i will test the farm, set the permissions & other
  tweaking, if it is working fine.
- I will run the 2nd script to deploy the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using DSC and the SharePoint DSC resources. A good tutorial is here

https://github.com/PowerShell/SharePointDSC

I have used this method with automating a highly customized version of SharePoint across several farms